# Drawing equal samples from each class in stratified sampling

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

So I have 1000 class 1 and 2500 class 2. So naturally when using:

sklearn's `train_test_split(test_size = 200, stratify = y)`. I get an imbalanced test set since it is preserving the data distribution from the original data set. However, I would like to split to have 100 class 1 and 100 class 2 in the test set.

How would I do it? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The title is somehow misleading. Should consider changing into something like "Draw equal number of samples per class in stratified sampling".

Answer (score 3):

### Split Manually

A manual solution isn't that scary. Main steps explained:

1. Isolate the index of class-1 and class-2 rows.
2. Use `np.random.permutation()` to select random `n1` and `n2` test samples for class 1 and 2 respectively.
3. Use `df.index.difference()` to perform inverse selection for the train samples.

The code can be easily generalized to arbitrary number of classes and arbitrary numbers to be selected as test data (just put n1/n2, idx1/idx2, etc. into lists and process by loops). But that's out of the scope of the question itself.

### Code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "label": np.array([1]*1000 + [2]*2500),
        # label 1 has value > 0, label 2 has value < 0
        "value": np.hstack([np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000),
                            np.random.uniform(-1, 0, 2500)])
    }
)
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

# sampling number for each class
n1 = 100
n2 = 100

# 1. get indexes and lengths for the classes respectively
idx1 = df.index.values[df["label"] == 1]
idx2 = df.index.values[df["label"] == 2]
len1 = len(idx1)  # 1000
len2 = len(idx2)  # 2500

# 2. draw index for test dataset
draw1 = np.random.permutation(len1)[:n1]  # keep the first n1 entries to be selected
idx1_test = idx1[draw1]
draw2 = np.random.permutation(len2)[:n2]
idx2_test = idx2[draw2]
# combine the drawn indexes
idx_test = np.hstack([idx1_test, idx2_test])

# 3. derive index for train dataset
idx_train = df.index.difference(idx_test)

# split
df_train = df.loc[idx_train, :]  # optional: .reset_index(drop=True)
df_test = df.loc[idx_test, :]
# len(df_train) = 3300
# len(df_test) = 200    

# verify that no row was missing
idx_merged = np.hstack([df_train.index.values, df_test.index.values])
assert len(np.unique(idx_merged)) == 3500
```

Comment: I would also like to know in there is a built-in function in sklearn/scipy/pandas capable of doing this. My survey on the official docs and google yielded nothing unfortunately.

Comment: I have also skimmed through several documentations with no luck. I just thought implementing a function by a package would be more "reliable" . Otherwise thanks for your suggestion.